# Using global instance of a class by another global variable in other file

Tags: c++, class, global-variables

I have these files (simplified version)

a.h

```
class A
{

public:
     A(int){}

int operator [](int a){return a;}
};

A a(2);
```

main.cpp

```
#include<a.h>

class B
{
public:
    B(int){}
};

B b(a[2]);

int main()
{
  //use b here...
}
```

Q: Can I use the above code ? Is it correct ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above (almost) compiles, but it probably doesn't do what you'd expect. A couple issues . . .

1. `#include<a.h>` should probably be `#include "a.h"` if a.h is located in the same directory as main.cpp.
2. `B b(a[2])` might create a new instance of class A, instead of using the one you defined in a.h. Add `extern A a;` before you use `a` to tell your compiler that you want to use the `a` declared in another file.

Finally, depending on your application sometimes global variables can be frowned upon. If it's appropriate, consider using encapsulation instead of global variables. Something like

```
Class B {

public:
    B(int i){}

private:
    A a(); // Or extern A a;
};
```

Would work if you only needed to access a from b.